# Delphi Bookmark Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier 'TBookmark'

Tags: delphi, vcl, firedac

Hey I wanted to use a TBookmark as a varialbe in my Form. I got it running in another Form and it is working there.

But in the new Form I get the Error.. I guess I have to include something in the uses statement but I cant remember what it was. Here is the code TBookmark is underlined in red so thats where the error sits.

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var test : string;
var selectedRow, rows : TBookmark;
begin
  rows := Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GetBookmark;
  Form1.DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
  Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(rows);
  test := Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('name').AsString;
  ShowMessage(test);

end;

end.
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here IMHO, but I suspect that the error is because you are accessing a grid in Form1 when the code is in Form4. Does Form4 'know about' Form1?

Comment: yh I included it in my uses Forn. But I have the error when I create the var.. And that should be possible or no?

Comment: Does Form4 declare the 'grids' and 'dbgrids' units?

Comment: Your Form4 needs to Use the DB unit, because that's where TBookMark is declared.

Comment: @No'amNewman no it doesnt I have few units but form4 uses all of them

Comment: "*I guess I have to include something in the uses statement but I cant remember what it was*" - that is what [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TBookmark) is for.  `TBookmark` is in the `Data.DB` unit (or just `DB` prior to XE2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Form4 needs to Use the DB unit, because that's where TBookMark is declared.

Btw, what is in Form1's unit is irrelevant to this.  The only relevant thing is that Form4's unit **has** to Use DB.  What happens is that when the compiler tries to compile your Form4 unit, it needs to be able to find the definition of TBookMark, and that is in the standard DB.Pas unit along with lots of other dataset-related stuff.  The same is true of any other identifier (or its class) that the compiler encounters in your project's source code.

99% of problems like this can be solved by doing a "Search | Find in Files" through Dephi's source code folders (and your project's folder if it's one of yours) to identify where the "undeclared" or missing item is declared.

**Update** So, you've got this code, which I'll assume is in your uForm4.Pas unit.

```
  procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    test : string;
  var
    selectedRow, rows : TBookmark;
  begin
    rows := Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GetBookmark;
    Form1.DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
    Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(rows);
    test := Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('name').AsString;
    ShowMessage(test);
  end;
```

You want to be able to do something with the Name value that's shown in the current row of
DBGrid1 on Form1.  There's nothing particularly wrong with the way you've done it, just that
it's long-winded, error-prone and invites problems like the one you've having with
TBookMark.

The point is that *somewhere* in your project, maybe in your uForm1.Pas unit, you know,
I don't, there must be a TDataSet-descendant (like TFDQuery, TAdoQuery or TTable) that is
specified in the `DataSet` property of Form1's DataSource1.  For the sake of argument, lets'
say that the dataset component is FDQuery1 on Form1 and you want to get the Name field value
from the current row in DBGrid1.

To get that Name value, you don't actually need the bookmarks your code is using.  The way
a TDBGrid works, the currently-selected row in the grid is **always** the current row in the
dataset component.  So you could simply write

```
    procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      test : string;
    begin
      test := Form1.FDQuery1.FieldByName('name').AsString;
      ShowMessage(test);
    end;
```

because you don't need to go through the rigmarole of `Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet` to get to it.

Now, to explain another little mystery, how come your code would work fine if it was in uForm1.Pas
but you get the `Undeclared Identifier: TBookMark` error why you try the same code in uForm4.Pas
unit?  Well, if you've ever watched the top of a source code file as it's being saved, you'll notice that
Delphi automatically adds, to the Uses list at the top, the units which contain any of the
components you've added to the form since its last save.  So adding a TDataSource to the form would add
the DB unit to the Uses list, because that's where TDataSource is declared and so is TBookMark.  Which
is why Delphi could compile Form1's code without the error, whereas when you try to mention a TBookMark
to uForm4, you need to add it to the unit's Uses list **unless** you add a component (like TDataSource)
to Form4 which will cause it to automatically add DB to the Uses list if it isn't already there.  Mystery
solved.

Comment: Okay - I understand what you mean but the weird thing is that my form4 is using all units in my project ( also the DB unit ). Is there a difference in using the units in the first uses call or in the second one so after implementation?  - I moved it in the implementation uses but got the same error:/

Comment: There should be no difference, **provided** that the first time the compiler encounters TBookMark in Form4's unit, it already knows that that unit Uses DB, so including it in tthe Uses list in its implementation section should be fine.  btw, writing `Form1.DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('name').AsString` is asking for trouble.  Somewhere in your project, there must be the dataset that DataSource1 refers to, so reference its FieldByName directly, not at 4 steps removed.

Comment: Ok basically I am taking a row from my dbgrid in Form1 (main form) and when I click on the DBNavigator Edit Button it should open a Form where I can edit the User so I get the values from the selected row wich works good because I can for example show it with a ShowMessage. In form4 is where I need that data comming from DBGrid Form1. I will try to figure out another way I guess. ty

Comment: A reason you are having a problem is that you are missing the point:  the data does **not** come from the DBGrid, it comes from the dataset connected to DataSource1 in Form1.  I will add something to my answer to show how you *should* be doing this.

Comment: Okay I understand but if I want to refer to the current selected row I have to go threw DBGrid right? At least thats why I found online. Again ty for helping I really need to wrap my head around delphi.

Comment: ty for your time. I will check it out as soon as I can and provide you some Feedback. But again thanks! Its really cool to get help from real Delphi PROS :)

Comment: No problem.  Please feel free to accept the answer if you find it useful/helpful.